# How can I password-protect an app folder in iOS?

Tags: iphone, security, password, folders

On my iPhone's home screen I have created a folder wherein I have placed few of my private apps which I don't have to be accessed if someone just incase uses my phone. How can I restrict the user from opening that folder or to be specific to how add passcode on the folder at iPhone's home screen.

I also search for appStore but didn't find any relevant app.

**Please note that I am not asking how to protect a single app. That I know I can handle by using guided access. But my question is around protecting an app folder without jailbreaking.**

Comment: Is jailbreaking an option for you?

Comment: @patrix : It isn't.

Comment: There's many apps on the App Store that allow you to password-protect files/folders **created/accessed within that app**.  There's no way of doing this with the base OS, you'll need to use a specific app.